# How to remove the # tab id in url using Visual composer in wordpress - Retailer Theme

Tags: javascript, url, tabs, hashtag

https://www.artvault.co.in/r-k-shrivastaw/#123

```
filesystem:chrome-extension://fdpohaocaechififmbbbbbknoalclacl/temporary/screencapture-artvault-co-in-wp-admin-theme-editor-php-1481961027761.png
```

No response this error is still coming.

Please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: What error? You haven't told us anything that would let us help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here, css are not linked properly to access from your application.

Please check all the resources like js,css are loaded properly

Comment: CSS and JS are linked properly go through this url https://www.artvault.co.in/r-k-shrivastaw/